# Восстановление файла данных данных из системного журнала в MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Всем привет, файл с данными моего SQL сервера был поврежден, и у меня нет резервной копии базы данных. Но как мне кажется нет никакой проблемы в файле системного журнала (ldf). Кто-либо может, пожалуйста, помочь в восстановлении данных от поврежденного mdf файла? Есть ли какие-либо проверенные методы чтобы возвратить данные файла с системного журнала?

Comment: Recovery model у базы какая была? Full, Simpe? SQL Server какой версии?

Answer (score 1):

Если бэкапа нет, то прежде чем пытаться доставать что-то из журнала транзакций, целесообразнее может быть сперва оценить потери, т.е. попробовать понять *что* именно в БД повреждено (может быть лог и не понадобится). Вы можете сделать это, запустив процедуру проверки [DBCC CHECKDB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms176064.aspx):

```
use [master]
GO
dbcc checkdb ([DbName]) with all_errormsgs
GO
```

Если база большая, то проверка может идти долго, дождитесь её завершения. Проинспектируйте выведенный отчёт. В зависимости от того какие ошибки найдутся (ошибки данных, индексов, метаданных, и т.п.) полное восстановление может быть или не быть возможным.

На эту тему есть статья ["Help, my database is corrupt. Now what?"](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Corruption/65804/)  (а [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/136979/) есть её перевод на русский), где вы можете прочесть какие действия можно предпринять далее.